# Getting Samba share volume id programmatically

Tags: c++, linux, samba

I need to know the serial of a volume shared with smb in c++. I get this id from Windows using GetVolumeInformation. In Linux I get the same from the bash, using

`$ smbclient '\\<ip>\<share>' -c volume`

How can I get the same in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could link your code with the `samba` package, and imitate what `smbclient` tool is doing. You can find it here: https://github.com/samba-team/samba/blob/master/source3/client/client.c#L4423

But the easy and reasonable thing will be to call this shell command directly from your program and read the output using `popen`. See an example
here:

[How do I execute a command and get the output of the command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po)